# EditText not using its attributes in XML

Tags: android, attributes, textview, android-softkeyboard

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/drawer_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:hint="@string/drawer_search_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
        android:textColorHint="@color/dark_blue" 
        />
```

So... all of the attributes work except imeOptions and maxlines. I want the text view to be only one line and the keyboard to not have a return key to go to the next line. It needs to submit/search what ever is in the text view. 
[image: before you press enter]

So this is the text view. cropped for space.

[image: after you press enter]

If you press enter/return it goes to the next line(which there should only be one line).
Why isn't the textview using all of the attributes?
Is there a better way to make it so the keyboard's return button is a submit button rather than next line?

The layout file is declared like this.

```
View headerRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute `android:maxLines` corresponds to the maximum height of the EditText or TextView. Use `android:singleLine=true` for one line input.

Comment: android:singleLine="true" will work but your reason for android:maxLines is not true. The reason it does not work is that android:maxLines would only be applicable if there is an android:inputType attribute. See document http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines